# Security considerations for connect-src CSP

Tags: security, content-security-policy

I'm trying to build a CSP policy that looks like following:

```
Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://*.example.com; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://*.example.com; font-src 'self'; connect-src *"
```

If you noticed everything is normal except for connect-src *.
We need to implement this as we are seeing scaling issues as we onboard new services which requires different endpoints to connect to. I want to understand what the security threats are if we allow connections to everything but restrict other derivates.

Comment: Also, even if I'm allowing connections to everything, but I've set script-src to self, does that mean it'll allow connections to everything but script will be restricted to self?

Answer (score 0):

The `connect-src` directive covers interfaces:

- `<a>` ping
- fetch
- XMLHttpRequest()
- sendBeacon()
- WebSocket
- EventSource

The "what security threats are if we allow connections to everything" depends on how do you use on the page the things which you are get via connect.

> even if I'm allowing connections to everything, but I've set script-src to self, does that mean it'll allow connections to everything but script will be restricted to self?

No. The `script-src` directive covers only sources for script loading/execution. `script-src 'self'` means that is allowed to load external scripts from the same `scheme:/domain:port_number` from where the page itself was loaded.

Fithermore, nothing prevents you from loading the script using XMLHTTPRequest from any source (because of `connect-src *`) and execute it.